# How do I detect an alt click on link in RichTextBox

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox in a WinForm with URL:s.
They can be clicked, but I want to detect if the user right clicked them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for. On the MouseDownEvent first check that you are dealing with a right click. Then figure out the clicked position and work your way back to the text.

```
    private void DoMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)sender;
            int charIndex = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            int lineIndex = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);
            string clickedText = rtb.Lines[lineIndex];

            // now check if the text was indeed a link
            Regex re = new Regex("http://(www\\.)?([^\\.]+)\\.([^\\.]+)");
            bool isLink = re.IsMatch(s);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: That will give me the text of the line, but I won't know if it's a link or something else on that line that was clicked. I could 'walk' the characters around the clicked position, but that is the kind of code I had hope to not write when using the built in functionality of the RichTextBox.

Comment: Why not just use regex to see is it's a link?

Regex re = new Regex("http://(www\\.)?([^\\.]+)\\.([^\\.]+)");
bool isLink = re.IsMatch(clickedText);

Am I getting closer to what you are after?

Comment: You still only see if the line you clicked contains a link not if you actually clicked the link. I'll just use the CharIndex and check if I'm actually ON the link.